# UISlider aceess through sender and class

Tags: ios, iphone

This aciton is called when sliding:

```
-(IBAction) sliding:(id)sender{
    UISlider *temp = (UISlider *) sender;
    int value = (int)temp.value;
    val.text= [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"%i",value ]; // val is the name oflabel   
}
```

But when i do this:

```
-(IBAction) sliding:(id)sender{

        int value = (int)sender->value;// ERROR(no member named value) WHY ?
        val.text= [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"%i",value ]; // val is the name of label   
    }
```

How can I get the value of slider without creating the instance of UISlider class

Comment: If your goal is to keep the sender as a generic `id`, I'm not sure if this helps at all, but `[sender description]` could be formatted to display the value

Answer (score 1):

You have to create the IBOutlet of UISlider and from that you can get the value.

```
@property(nonatomic,weak) IBOutlet UISlider *slider;
-(IBAction) sliding:(id)sender
{
val.text= [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"%i",self.slider.value];    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
int value = (int)((UISlider *)sender->value);
```

Answer (score 0):

I made the Slider variable an outlet and got the value from .value, i.e the getter of myslider.

INTERFACE

> 

```
{  
   UISlider *slide;
   UILabel *val; 
  }

@property(nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet UISlider *slide;
```

IMPLEMENTATION:

```
-(IBAction) sliding:(id)sender{
   //UISlider *temp = (UISlider *) sender;
    int value = (int)slide.value;
    val.text= [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"%i",value ];    
}
```

But i Would still like it know how to get it through sender???